# JavaScript Closure - listen event for all elements of a class

Tags: javascript, dom, google-closure, google-closure-library

Is it possible to bind an event to all elements of a class in Closure? I know in jQuery it's something like

```
$('.my_class').click(...)
```

Is there something similar in Closure? Something like

```
goog.events.listen('.my_class', ...)
```

Comment: Unfortunately, not really. A normal loop over a `querySelectorAll` `NodeList` would be easiest.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean something like below?

Reference: http://closure-library.googlecode.com/git-history/docs/namespace_goog_events.html

```
var source = new goog.events.EventTarget();
  function handleEvent(e) {
    alert('Type: ' + e.type + '; Target: ' + e.target);
  }
  source.listen('foo', handleEvent);
  // Or: goog.events.listen(source, 'foo', handleEvent);
  ...
  source.dispatchEvent('foo');  // will call handleEvent
  ...
  source.unlisten('foo', handleEvent);
  // Or: goog.events.unlisten(source, 'foo', handleEvent);
```

Answer (score 0):

As joeltine already mentioned, there is no such native method in Google Closure Lib. You can use the G-Library:
https://github.com/rhysbrettbowen/G-closure#gon-uid

Or create another prototype to provide an advanced listen-method. These fragements can serve the fundamental elements:

```
yourapp.prototype.listenAll = function(nodes, callbackFunc) {
  for (var i = 0; i < nodes.length; i++) {
    goog.events.listen(nodes[i], type, callbackFunc);
  }
};
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Generally, links to a tool or library [should be accompanied by usage notes, a specific explanation of how the linked resource is applicable to the problem, or some sample code](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251605), or if possible all of the above.

Comment: Ok I specified the link the best I could